# How can I split the server message on Android

Tags: android, sockets, android-studio, split

I know a few command on java, but this is the first time I encounter this problem. for example the message of the server is "111||222||333". How can a client split the message on a 3 textbox? the output must be textbox1=111, textbox2=222 and textbox3=333.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a basic Java method for your purpose:

[Split method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

```
String[] separated = "111||222||333".split("||");
separated[0]; // Contain 111 
separated[1]; // Contain 222
separated[2]; // Contain 111
```

Then just set your Text in your "Textbox" (Called TextView in Android):

```
TextView tv111 = (TextView) getActivity().findviewbyid(R.id.textview_111);
TextView tv222 = (TextView) getActivity().findviewbyid(R.id.textview_222);
TextView tv333 = (TextView) getActivity().findviewbyid(R.id.textview_333);
tv111.setText(separated[0]);
tv222.setText(separated[1]);
tv333.setText(separated[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split() of String it will give you array of splited strings.

```
String str[] = "111||222||333".split("||");
String textbox1 = str[0];
String textbox2 = str[1];
String textbox3 = str[2];
```

And if your thread.socketdata's  value is varying like  "111||222||333||444||...." then follow this-

```
String str[] = thread.socketdata.split("||");

for(int i=0 ; i<str.length ; i++)
{
    switch(i)
    {
    case 0:
        textbox1 = str[i];
        break;
    case 1:
        textbox2 = str[i];
        break;
    case 2:
        textbox3 = str[i];
        break;
    case 3:
        textbox4 = str[i];
        break;
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you,, but can I use it if the message is varying? is it ok if String str[ ] = thread.socketdata.split("||"). the "thread.socketdata" is the message of the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String[] splits = "111||222||333".split("||");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
TextView first = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstText);
TextView second = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondText);
TextView third = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.thirdText);
...

String response = "111||2222||3333";
String[] messages = response.split("||");
first.setText(messages[0]);
second.setText(messages[1]);
third.setText(messages[2]);
```

Comment: thank you,, but can I use it if the message is varying? is it ok if String str[ ] = thread.socketdata.split("||"). the "thread.socketdata" is the message of the server

Comment: yes, you could do it with whatever a string if the strings in it are separated with `||` (this is exactly the separator). It could be <something>||<anything>||<something more> for example

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use simple `string.split("||")` as `|` is character for **OR** in regex.
`string.split("||")` is equal to `string.split("")`. It will split your string to character level.
Use this

```
string.split("\\|\\|");
```

`\` is regex escape character